# Uploading Video to Youtube and return URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

[Javascript for uploading videos
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples)

I've used the example code and modify by changing the Client ID.

What I hope to achieve is using Javascript to get the URL or Video ID return which I can store at the database to use later.
The example code will show the video after it has successfully uploaded, when I click on the video, there is an option to get the video url. Is it possible to get the url automatically by javascript?

I've search for this topic but I can't find any similar solution.